# Leaving and re-entering Canada with an expired study permit

Tags: visas, canada, permits

To clarify things, my study permit expired early in March. However, I did apply to extend my study permit before the expiry date, so I am legally allowed to be in Canada by implied status. About a week ago, I received an email saying my application for the study permit extension was approved. The problem is, I have to leave the country today and the new study permit is still being delivered by mail to my Canadian address. So my questions are:

What should I expect coming to the airport, leaving the country, with an expired study permit? (Note that technically I did not overstay and at no point was I required to leave the country).

How can I go back to Canada if the required documents are in my Canadian address and I will be overseas with an expired Canadian study permit? Should I have someone inside the country mail it to me?

Thank you.

Comment: If someone can mail/courier you the documents, that would be ideal.  Otherwise, do you have any other evidence of your study permit having been renewed?

Comment: Should I have someone inside the country mail it to me? Yes, that would solve all the problems.

Comment: Note to close-voters:  this is not a question about moving to Canada to study;  this is a question about briefly traveling to & from a country where one is legally resident but does not currently have the papers to prove it.  I would think this question fits better on this site than it would on Expats.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I disagree. The OPS right to remain in Canada AND their ability to leave and return to Canada are based on a visa/long term study permit which was acquired for a long term stay. That is completely on-topic for expatriates. If you feel that strongly about disagreeing, please note, this question is only on hold, you are able to nominate for reopening.